# tensorflow How to restore a graph from meta and place it on a different device

Tags: python, graph, tensorflow, meta

How can i just restore the structure from the meta graph file, and then ONLY change the device it was placed on for a deployment use ?

I have started several different training process with a same python script but in different configurable params like: unit size, layer number, Cell type(LSTM or GRU) ... which I don't want to keep track of in detail. What i think is the most convenient for me is to simply import everything except the device placement of the model, place it on the device for deployment and initialize it with a pre-trained parameters in some checkpoint files.

Since i didn't find a way for that, can any one shed some light on it?

Answer (score 2):

The [`freeze_graph`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) function can export your model in a protobuf file. This function has the parameter `clear_devices` that can be set to `True` to remove from the graph definition the device placement.

Looking at the source code of `freeze_graph` you can see how to manually remove the device from the graph definition:

```
  # Remove all the explicit device specifications for this node. This helps to
  # make the graph more portable.
  if clear_devices:
    for node in input_graph_def.node:
      node.device = ""
  _ = tf.import_graph_def(input_graph_def, name="")
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm gonna try it